# Which versions of django can I use with google cloud sql?

Tags: django, google-cloud-sql

I would like to know which versions of django can I use with google cloud sql. I am currently trying 1.8 but I guess it is not supported.

Is there any documentation on supported version?

Thank you

Comment: are you talking about Google App Engine right ?

Comment: yes, I want to use django on appengine using google cloud sql.

Comment: which version of Django. By default Google App engine support 1.5 but external library you can extend with 1.9

Comment: for more information please see this link https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton

Comment: Thank you, I read in that project that "Please note that only 1st generation CloudSQL instance are currently supported for Google App Engine applications." Is this still correct? I would like to use second generation. Thanks

Comment: yeah so far I heard they support first gen right now... I think we may wait for second gen support

Comment: Please read my answer, you can use first OR second generation at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

So, after contacting google cloud support to be sure about the possibilities, I will answer my question:

You can use any version of Django in appengine, you can install it to a lib module and then add the file appengine_config.py with the lines:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

If you want to use the django mysql backend you can do so and you can use Google Cloud SQL first OR second generation. I am currently using second generation. There is a free trial and good documentation > https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django